# Remove elements from a BS4 ResultSet if they are in another BS4 ResultSet

Tags: python, jquery, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, list-comprehension

I am trying to make a web crawler - scraper to get the news.
I want to remove elements that are in a specific class. But, the problem is that this class is nested in another class.
The code is below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.moneyreview.gr/life-and-arts/86916/mia-apli-lysi-gia-to-rochalito-to- 
kolpo-poy-sozei-chiliades-gamoys/'

r1 = requests.get(url)
coverpage = r1.content
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(coverpage, 'html5lib')
title = soup1.find('h1').get_text()
article = requests.get(url)
article_content = article.content

soup_article = BeautifulSoup(article_content, 'html5lib')
body = soup_article.find_all('div', class_='entry-content')
```

**The unwanted elements**
Inside the text of the article there is also the text of a tweet. I want to remove this text and all twitter tags etc from the article text so that I have a clean text.
I wrote this code to print everything inside this twitter tag:

```
for elements in body:
   quote = soup1.find_all('blockquote', class_= "twitter-tweet")
   print(quote)
```

**I get this result :**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt3j3.png)

With the code below I put the paragraphs of the text in a list:

```
x = body[0].find_all('p')
list_paragraphs = []

for p in np.arange(0, len(x)):
    paragraph = x[p].text.replace("\n", " ")
    list_paragraphs.append(paragraph)
```

**Where the problem is:**
I want everything inside the list `quote` to be removed from the list `list_paragraphs`.
But all I tried so far, failed.

```
my_list = []

for i in quote:
   if i:
       my_list.append(i.text.strip())
print(my_list)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEKB1.png)

## Attempt 1

```
l3 = [x for x in list_paragraphs if x not in my_list]
print(l3)
```

## Attempt 2

```
for element in my_list:
    if element in list_paragraphs:
        list_paragraphs.remove(element)
```

**Can you suggest something to do?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want all the text inside the `<p>` tags, unless it is enclosed in a `<blockquote>` with the class `twitter-tweet`. If that is the case, I would say, the easiest way to accomplish this, is to simply get rid of all the offending `<blockquote>` tags. You can do that with [`decompose`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) for instance. Basically you find all those tags as you already did, using `find_all` and then call `.decompose()` on each one.

I took the liberty of optimizing your code a bit, as I understood it. Here is my suggestion:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = ...
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')
for quote in soup.find_all('blockquote', class_="twitter-tweet"):
    quote.decompose()
content_div = soup.find('div', class_='entry-content')
list_paragraphs = []
for p in content_div.find_all('p'):
    text = p.get_text(strip=True).replace("\n", " ")
    if text:
        list_paragraphs.append(text)

print(list_paragraphs)
```

1. In your original code you made the same request to that url twice for some reason, so I reduced it to a single request.
2. When you know that you always want the first `<div>` with the class `entry-content`, you can use [`find`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) instead of `find_all`.
3. Calling [`.get_text(strip=True)`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) on each paragraph tag strips the text of all whitespace.
4. I thought it would make little sense to keep empty strings in your `list_paragraphs`, so inside the loop we only append a `text`, if it is not empty.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be using [`extract`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) to remove twitter content as shown below:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'your_url'
unwanted_tags = ['blockquote']

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
# remove tweets from content
for tag in unwanted_tags: [i.extract() for i in soup(tag)]

main_content = [i for i in list(map(lambda x: x.get_text(), soup.find_all('p'))) if i not in ['','\n']]
print(''.join(main_content))
```